# 25: syntax error in literal set Context: ...C ; in MathProg model processing error

Tags: glpk

I have a problem with the last two functions of my code. can someone help me?

> project.c:25: syntax error in literal set Context: ...C ; subject to
>   setofitem { j in N } : Yj [ j ] >= sum { j in MathProg model
>   processing error

```
param m, integer, >=0;    #number of items
param n, integer, >=0;    #number of buyers
set M := 1..m;            #set of indices of items
set N := 1..n;            #set of indices of buyers
set S {1..n};             #subset of j

param k {M};             #seller's supply (fortinura venditore )
param v {N};             #given value of j for_SJ

var C >=0;  
var Pj {N} >=0;           #paymemt of buyer j 
var Yj {N}, binary;       #1if obtains preferred subset Sj
var Xij {M,N}, binary;    #1if J obtains an item i #supply costants

subject to production {i in M}:
sum {j in N} Xij[i,j] <= k[i];

subject to payment {j in N}:          #no more than Vj
Pj[j] <= v[j] * Yj[j];

subject to anyotherbuyer {j in N}:
Pj[j] <= C;

#subject to setofitem {j in N}:
#Yj[j] >= sum {j in N} Xij[i,j] - (|S[j]|-1)  ;

#subject to any {j in N}:
#C <= v[j]*Yj[j] +(1-Yj[j]) * sum {j in N} v[j]   ;

maximize revenue:
sum {j in N} Pj[j];


solve;
printf "the objective function value is %.3f\n", revenue;

end;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
subject to setofitem {j in N}:
Yj[j] >= sum {j in N} Xij[i,j] - (|S[j]|-1)  ;
```

You use the same index j for the constraint and the sum and i is undefined. Please, check your indices.

There is no || operator in GLPK. Use abs().